# Is there anyway to send the scanned QR code results directly to the server?

Tags: java, android, qr-code, zxing

I have developed an **android app for scanning QR Codes** and send it over the server.
In this app i am getting multiple QR code scanned results in a list-view using an array list and sending them to the server on a button click event.
**The requirement is to send all the scanned QR-code results directly to the
server without using any of the events e.g button click or something like that.**
Here i am using zxing QR scanner using intent. Below is the code for getting the QR-code scan result.

```
       @Override
       public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
       if (requestCode == SCANNER_REQUEST_CODE) {
        // Handle scan intent
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // Handle successful scan
            String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
            String formatName = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
            byte[] rawBytes = intent.getByteArrayExtra("SCAN_RESULT_BYTES");
            int intentOrientation = intent.getIntExtra(
                    "SCAN_RESULT_ORIENTATION", Integer.MIN_VALUE);
            Integer orientation = (intentOrientation == Integer.MIN_VALUE) ? null
                    : intentOrientation;
            String errorCorrectionLevel = intent
                    .getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_ERROR_CORRECTION_LEVEL");

            QRContent = contents;
            QR_Receivd.setText(QRContent);
            listItems.add(QRContent); //adding scan result to an array list(listItems)

        } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // Handle cancel
        }

     //On-click method to initiate scan.

     @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.btScan) {
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
    intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "SCAN_MODE");
    startActivityForResult(intent, SCANNER_REQUEST_CODE);
   }  
 }
```

So instead of using on-click event **i want to send the scanned result    directly to a server immidiately after getting the result from the  scanner.
    Thanks!!!**

Answer (score 1):

**Part 1**

first you should pick how you want to send it. you can send it using the official tools, or using 3rd party libraries. i'll assume the later.

on my approach you will need, on the server, a PHP file in charge of recieving (by GET or by POST) the scanned QR as parameter.

example call :

myserver.com/API/addqr?qrcode=XXXXXXXXXX

this PHP file must then save that to your database, i suppose MYSQL.

**PART 2**

now that you have your server set, you should take a look at the different libs or the official documentation.

[USING VOLLEY](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html)

[Using Loopj's Android Async HTTP petitions (i reccomend this)](https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http)

i will assume you pick method 2.

all you have to do is  send the petition :

```
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            //blah blah blah all the code that decodes and adds it to the listview
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
        params.put("qrcode", "XXXXXXXXXXXXX");
 client.post("myserver.com/API/addqr", params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {

        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
          //do something with the response, if there is one.
        }

    });

        }
```